# ConfigurationBuilder haven't definition for AddJson

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to use connection string from my json file by doing next steps

Json file

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "PlatformDatabase": "Server=xxxx\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=xxxx;Trusted_Connection=True;"
    }
}
```

Access to json

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
              .SetBasePath(System.AppContext.BaseDirectory)
              .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json",
                  optional: true,
                  reloadOnChange: true);

Configuration = builder.Build();

optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PlatformDatabase"));
```

> **Error:** ConfigurationBuilder does not contain a definition for
>   AddJsonFile.

Does anyone have this problem before? I tried searching it but all the solution I found doesn't work now (i suppose with version 2).

**EDIT**

note. I created .Net Core 2.0 console application

Comment: I just used this for an Inegration test and worked perfectly, also works with .Net core 2.1

Answer (score 9):

The problem was solved by install the nuget package

> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to explicit add `appsettings.json` in ASP.NET Core 2.

You just need the followings inside `Startup.cs` -

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
       Configuration.GetConnectionString("PlatformDatabase")));

    ...
    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ...
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

### Another Approach

You register ***IConfiguration*** as ***Singleton*** in ***DI container***, and then inject it to your DBContext constructor. Then get the connection string inside `OnConfiguring` method.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }

    private IConfiguration _config;

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton(_config);
        services.AddDbContext<YOUR_DB_Context>(ServiceLifetime.Scoped);

        ...

        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

**YOUR_DB_Context.cs**

```
public class YOUR_DB_Context : IdentityDbContext OR DbContext
{
    private IConfiguration _config;

    public YOUR_DB_Context(DbContextOptions options, IConfiguration config)
        : base(options)
    {
        _config = config;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        ...
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_config["Data:PlatformDatabase"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Win, thanks for the answer is it the same case for a console application?

Comment: I could not say for sure for console app. You could give a try using second approach, if first one does not work.